# Strange error message when installing core (Jane st Ocaml library)

Tags: ocaml, opam

I receive the following error while trying to install core with opam.

```
==== ERROR [while installing core.109.42.00] ====
# opam-version    1.0.0
# os              linux
# command         make
# path            /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/build/core.109.42.00
# exit-code       2
# env-file        /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/build/core.109.42.00/core-5f1023.env
# stdout-file     /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/build/core.109.42.00/core-5f1023.out
# stderr-file     /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/build/core.109.42.00/core-5f1023.err
### stdout ###
...[truncated]
/home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/bin/ocamlopt.opt unix.cmxa -I /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/                                                                                              lib/ocaml/ocamlbuild /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/lib/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuildlib                                                                                              .cmxa myocamlbuild.ml /home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/lib/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild.c                                                                                              mx -o myocamlbuild
ocamlfind ocamlc -I lib -package core_kernel -c lib/backtrace_stubs.c
mv backtrace_stubs.o lib/backtrace_stubs.o
ocamlfind ocamlc -I lib -package core_kernel -c lib/bigstring_stubs.c
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -I lib -package core_kernel -c lib/bigstring_stubs.c
lib/bigstring_stubs.c: In function ‘bigstring_recvmmsg_assume_fd_is_nonblocking_                                                                                              stub’:
lib/bigstring_stubs.c:592:18: error: array type has incomplete element type
lib/bigstring_stubs.c:639:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘recvmmsg                                                                                              ’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
lib/bigstring_stubs.c:592:18: warning: unused variable ‘hdrs’ [-Wunused-variable                                                                                              ]
Command exited with code 2.
### stderr ###
/tmp/cc5m08R9.o: In function `main':
test_recvmmsg.c:(.text+0x24): warning: recvmmsg is not implemented and will alwa                                                                                              ys fail
E: Failure("Command ''/home/cesally/.opam/4.01.0/bin/ocamlbuild' lib/libcore_stubs                                                                                              .a lib/dllcore_stubs.so lib/core.cma lib/core.cmxa lib/core.a lib/core.cmxs top/                                                                                              core_top.cma top/core_top.cmxa top/core_top.a top/core_top.cmxs -tag debug' term                                                                                              inated with error code 10")
make: *** [build] Error 1

'opam install core' failed.
```

I can't quite understand this error message, can any ocaml hackers shed some light?

I am on ubuntu, without admin rights. Thanks

Edit: g++ version is 4.6.3

Comment: Rerun it with *-v* option and show tail of the log, please. Also we need output of `g++ --version`.

Comment: @Kakadu The tail is the same as what I posted. Not sure what you're looking for so I've put it in a pastebin.
 http://pastebin.com/CfCiMhFK

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the core configure script and the C compiler are in disagreement on whether `recvmmsg` is available on your system. I guess it is a bug in core. First, try the latest version (at time of this writing it is 110.something), and if it is not fixed yet report it to core authors.